# using applescript to display Unix Exctable file

Tags: unix, applescript

I want to use applescript to create a application to run a Unix Executable File. I would like the information from the Unix exe file to be displayed within applescript. Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
set aVariable to do shell script "fullPathToYourExecutable"
display dialog aVariable
```

Comment: Can you send me an example?

Comment: set aVariable to do shell script "echo " & quoted form of "Shell script result"

Comment: set aVariable to do shell script "/usr/bin/mdfind -onlyin ~/ -name .xcodeproj"