# How do you use data that is returned from a tell function in applescript?

Tags: applescript

I'm pretty new to applescript, but I think I'm getting the gist of it. I'm trying to write something that enables/disables the requiring of a password on waking from sleep, but what I need to do is get the value that this returns and set it to a variable that can be viewed later.

```
tell application "System Events" to set security preferences's require password to wake to not (security preferences's require password to wake)
```

In the result, true or false show up, which is what I want to show up in a dialog, though I'm going to reword it. I don't know how to take the result's value, however. The problem is that since the require password to wake is inside of a tell, I don't know how to retrieve its boolean value.

My whole script is this. I know it's probably very messy, but it's pretty much my first applescript experience.

```
tell application "System Events" to set security preferences's require password to wake to not (security preferences's require password to wake)
tell application "System Events" to return security preferences's require password to wake as boolean
tell application "System Events" to return security preferences's require password to wake as boolean
if the "require password to wake" is false then display dialog (password_req as boolean)
if the "require password to wake" is false then display dialog (password_req as boolean)
if boolean = true then display dialog (boolean as text)
if boolean = false then display dialog (boolean as text)
get "require password to wake" as text
display dialog "require password to wake"
beep
display alert "Password toggled."
return
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15015172/using-applescript-to-display-unix-exctable-file/15016054#15016054

Answer (score 0):

```
tell application "System Events"
 --note that this is a 'true tell block' as opposed to a one-liner
 set security preferences's require password to wake to not (security preferences's require password to wake)
 --above line can't return result. to do that you do:
 set passReq to security preferences's require password to wake
end tell--block end

--ok, you've toggled it. now report it:

display dialog ("Password required is set to " & (passReq as text))
```

Comment: A little further basic explanation: a block is not a function, and a function is known as a handler in AppleScript. A tell block sends specific apple events to an appropriate process/app, or to an object (like a window, word, etc.). To return from a handler, you put what you want to return at the very end of the handler. Good study material here: http://www.apeth.net/matt/unm/asph.html